# Ruby on rails server issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to ROR. I have installed ruby, rails and all. I have a problem. When I type `rails server`, the server starts but the `localhost:3000 page` shows an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TasksController#index
>
> Could not find table 'tasks'
>
> Rails.root: C:/Sites/todo Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full
>   Trace
>
> app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:4:in `new'
>   app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:4:in`index'
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> None
>
> Show session dump
>
> Show env dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> None

Please help

Comment: Show your schema.rb file (db/schema.rb). Looks like you created controller on model Tasks, but did not create model and migrations.

Comment: What needed to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you dont have a table named `Task` and you are trying to use it in the controller .First you need to verify that you have a table named `tasks` created... including model `task.rb` with a `migration` file to generate the `tasks table`

Comment: can you help me on this? i am very new to ROR. How to create table named tasks and other to correct this?